# Redirect from subdomain (ab-xyz.rhcloud.com) to custom domain

Tags: .htaccess, openshift

I want redirect my openshift subdomain (*.rhcloud.com) to my custom domain when my visitors access subdomain. I tried using .htaccess for redirect but I got an Redirect error on mozilla firefox. This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://customdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app-domain\.rhcloud\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://customdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

You are missing where it looks for the old domain to redirect, so you are getting a redirect loop.